# Convert code snippet from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, code-conversion

I have tried a number of freely available code converters to convert the following piece, however without success.

```
 Dim resultList = ((From e In p_Xml.Elements()
                       Where UCase(e.Name.LocalName) = searchName).Union(
                         From a In p_Xml.Attributes()
                         Where UCase(a.Name.LocalName) = searchName
                         Select <<%= propertyName %>><%= a.Value %></>)).ToList()
```

I think I got it here

```
var resultList = (from e in p_xml.Elements()
                where e.Name.LocalName == searchName
                select propertyName).
Union(from a in p_xml.Attributes()
      where a.Name.LocalName == searchName
      select a.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: What were the issues you had? Possibly they got confused by the use of ASP.NET inline code.

Comment: You weren't selecting any items on the left side of the union!

Answer (score 1):

Your conversion left out `UCase`, whose equivalent in C# is `ToUpperCase`.

This is not the recommended way to perform case-insensitive string comparisons, though.

`e.Name.LocalName == searchName`

should be replaced with something like:

`String.Compare(e.Name.LocalName, searchNamename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0`

Also, what is `propertyName`? Whatever it is, its value is obviously not dependent on `e`. You're selecting one and the same thing for every `e` in your first query, which makes no sense. I guess you meant `select e`.

What you probably want then is something along the lines of:

```
var resultList = (from e in p_xml.Elements()
                where String.Compare(e.Name.LocalName, searchName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0
                select e).
Union(from a in p_xml.Attributes()
      where String.Compare(a.Name.LocalName, searchName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0
      select a.Value).ToList();
```

I'm only not sure how to represent `Select <<%= propertyName %>><%= a.Value %></>` in C#, since I don't know VB.

Answer (score 0):

Good online Code Converter that I use all the time is http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: It does not really help him (it reports an InvalidOperationException when attempting to convert his code sample), plus he mentioned that he `tried a number of freely available code converters`, and when I google "code converter", your link comes second on the search results list ( first for the query "c# vb code converter"), which means it is rather unlikely that he's not aware of that website...

Answer (score 0):

I heard from Microsoft's [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh500769) project in a presentation. Maybe that can help you.

Microsoft want to integrate *Roslyn* in a future Visual Studio version. Then it would be possible to just **copy code from VB to clipboard and paste it as C# code**. There was also a presentation about that in last year, maybe the same one.